# Program compiles with and without return 0

Tags: c++, return, statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should main() return in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c)

This is a pretty basic question, I guess.

I've been programming for a year now but a friend of mine surprised me with a rather stupefying question.

Programs that start with 'int main()' on C++ seem to compile perfectly even with 'return 0;' removed and not replaced by any other return statement. And without a return statement at all, the program still shows that 'Process returned 0'.

Does this have any explanation? 
Sorry if my question is silly!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should main() return in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c)

Answer (score 5):

§3.6.1/5:

> A return statement in `main` has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and calling `exit` with the return value as the argument. If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing
>   `return 0;`

Answer (score 1):

From the accepted answer of [What should main() return in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c)

> It's also worth noting that in C++, int main() can be left without a return value at which point it defaults to returning 0. This is also true with a C99 program. Whether return 0 should be omitted or not is open to debate.